# filtering a dictionary(of int64, myObject) from a dictionary(of int64, int64)

Tags: .net, vb.net, dictionary, filter

I have 2 dictionaries;

- A : dictionary(of int64, myObject)
- B : dictionary(of int64, int64).

I want to filter (or get another filtered dictionary) dictionary A from dictionary B. I mean, dictonary B contains some keys/values of dictionary A keys, and I want an A dictionary with these keys only.

Just in case, B hasn't to be a dictionary of(int64, int64), it could be a list, an array or anything else if it helps.

Thank you very much!

PS: I know i can do it with a for inside a for, but I guess (hope?) there would be a more efficient way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help? `Customer` has one property `ID` of type `int64`.

```
    Dim foo As New Dictionary(Of Int64, Int64)
    Dim bar As New Dictionary(Of Int64, Customer)

    foo.Add(1, 5)
    foo.Add(2, 99)
    foo.Add(3, 222)
    foo.Add(4, 333)

    bar.Add(1, New Customer(5, "john"))
    bar.Add(55, New Customer(323, "ringo"))
    bar.Add(4, New Customer(333, "george"))

    Dim common = From f In foo, b In bar _
                    Where f.Key = b.Key _
                    And f.Value = b.Value.ID _
                    Select b

    For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of Int64, Customer) In common
        Console.WriteLine(item.Key & " " & item.Value.ID & " " & item.Value.Name)
    Next

 ....

Public Class Customer
   Public ID As Int64
   Public Name As String
End Class
```

Comment: Hi! It worked, thank you very much! However, I can't figured out how to convert the "common" to a dictionary(of int64, myobject). I've tried using KeySelector As Func(Of MyObject, Int64) in common.todictionary, but i get an error. I'll appreciate your advice! thanks!

Comment: @Leo - take a peek at the revised answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem is I can't convert "common" into a dictionary(of int64, myobject). Anyways, I've changed a parameter in the called function to accept the "common" type. Regards!